# Session variable not work properly when redirect from one page to other with mediator page in between

Tags: javascript, php, session, redirect

In below code,when i redirect from one page to redirection.php page with session variable it works well.

I implement this scenario with one button,But i have two button with below condition like when the user is already log-in then it will redirect to redirection.php page with link appended which is already stored in session variable because it will use elsewhere.Up to this there is no issue.

But when the user is not log-in and when i click on button it gives popup division for login(loginpopup.php page already included that's why will shows popup on click) and when the user is login with username/password then and then only it will redirect to the redirection.php page with stored product link which is in session variable.

And MY query is when i used that session variable in loginpopup.php page it doesn't get that particular product link which i should appended to redirect to redirection.php page.means the stored data in session variable not get proper link.

In short when i redirect from one page to other with mediator page in between(without page refresh) how can i use session variable.

```
<?php include("loginpopup.php"); $i = 0; //init number for ++
$a=array(
    array("Htc 526 black","htc.jpg",23000,"http://www.flipkart.com"),
    array("Iphone 6s","apple.jpg",43000,"http://www.amazon.com"),
    array("Sony xperia c3 dual","sony.jpg",19000,"http://www.snapdeal.com")
); foreach($a as $value){
//session_start();
$_SESSION['link'][$i]=$value[3];
echo $_SESSION['link'][$i];
if (isset($_SESSION['uname']) && $_SESSION['uname'] == true)
{?>
    <script>
        function Redirect1(i)
        {
            window.location="redirection.php?d="+i;
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "Redirect1(<?= $i ?>);" style="background-color:#ff8c21;">Buy Now</button>                
<?php
}
else
{?>

    <button type="button" id="aaa" class="btn btn-info btn-md" href = "javascript:void(0)" style="background-color:#ff8c21;"onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';" >Buy Now</button>     
<?php
}$i++;}?>
```

Then in redirection.php

```
<?php
if(session_id()=="")
{
session_start();
}
$i = $_GET['d'];
$deep_link=$_SESSION['link'][$i];
echo $deep_link;
?>
```

I hope you understand my issue,please suggest the proper way.

Comment: waiting for your reply

Comment: If you have done session_start(); in all the php pages, you should not technically face an issue accessing session variables. Have you done that?

Comment: ya i also start session in my mediator page (i.e. loginpopup.php) where i should use session variable

Comment: ya i also start session in my mediator page and also get value but it only take first link  instead i wan't that perticular link(click on first button get http://www.flipkart.com,click on second button get http://www.amazon.com,etc..) it only possible when i direct redirect to other page without any mediator but i wan't specific link in my loginpopup.php page also(i.e. mediator page) that's why i am using session

Comment: Your redirection code is right. It has session_start() at the top. But in your session_start() on the top before including loginpopup.php and let me know g that worked. What I understand from your question is that the loginpopup.php does not have access to session variable. Is that correct? `redirect from one page to other with mediator page in between(without page refresh) `. What are you doing here that the page does not refresh. The pages refresh all the time unless you are using Single Page Client side applications. Can you shed some light here?